# Prediction with Linear Regression with ARIMA errors

Tags: regression, arima

I have a simple question. If we fit a linear model $Y=a+bX+e$ where e~$N(0,1)$ and make a prediction for a given value of $X$, in the expectation, the $e$ is 0 so the expected value is $a+bX$. If we fit a linear regression with ARIMA errors (an Arimax), and want to use the resulting $b$ coefficients on X, not to forecast per say but to make predictions about Y if the values of X changed, can this still be done?

Comment: Short answer is yes. What Arima errors does is that it makes your standard errors efficient or unbiased for statistical significance testing. Other than that, ARIMAX is simply a linear regression.